# MPAndroidChart setting chart padding / offset

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart for my bar graph and I'm struggling with removing the padding of the graph (see pic below)

[image]

My approaches regarding this problem were:

1. ```
   chart.setDrawLegend(false);
   chart.setDrawMarkerViews(false);
   chart.setDrawUnitsInChart(false);
   chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
   chart.setDrawXLabels(false);
   chart.setDrawYLabels(false);
   chart.setDescription("");
   ```
2. ```
   chart.setOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
   chart.getTransformer().prepareMatrixValuePx(chart);
   chart.getTransformer().prepareMatrixOffset(chart);
   chart.getContentRect().set(0, 0, chart.getWidth(),chart.getHeight());
   ```

And nothing has worked so far. Do you know another approach for this problem?

Answer (score 14):

I know that's pretty late for answer, but now Chart has the following method:

```
setViewPortOffsets(-40f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
```

(setting weird -40f value instead 0 seems unnatural, but it still works)

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on an update that will allow to set all paddings!

The currently available method for setting the offsets is buggy.

In the meantime you could try to **set a negative padding or margin via .xml**.
Let me know if this works!

Comment: Negative margin does only work for left and right, but not for bottom margins. I tested it for LineCharts in a CardView.

Comment: @Strassenrenner I set all of them to negative and it worked

Comment: @Philip Jahoda I am using combined chart and want to set offset on x axis but its not working even tried setting negative margin.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
barChart.getAxisLeft().setXOffset(-9f);
```