# MPAndroidChart: Remove start padding of x-axis labels in BarChart

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, mpandroidchart

[image]

As shown in the image above, **is there any way to remove the start padding in my x-axis labels?** I've tried each of the following codes individually and altogether but they don't seem to do anything:

```
mBarChart.getXAxis().setXOffset(-50f);
mBarChart.setExtraLeftOffset(-50f);
mBarChart.setPadding(-50, 0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Call:**

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Check this [setting chart padding / offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563051/mpandroidchart-setting-chart-padding-offset) answer.

Comment: I've checked that thread a while back, however, it didn't provide any solution to my problem. Still, thanks btw.