# Remove Empty Spaces from the MPAndroidChart Horizontal Chart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to create a chart inside my application.

I want to remove all the empty space that is not covered by the graph. As you can see, there are some empty spaces for all 4 sides.

[image]

I tried using `HorizontalBarChart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)` function but it does not seems to be fully working.

Here is my Code.

```java
package com.example.unimarks

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.PercentFormatter
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate

class SummaryFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        buildMarkDistributionChart()
        buildCourseProgressChart()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false)
    }

    private fun buildMarkDistributionChart() {
        // (CODE FOR OTHER GRAPH)
    }
    private fun buildCourseProgressChart() {
        val chart = view?.findViewById<HorizontalBarChart>(R.id.course_progress_chart)
        val chartList : ArrayList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()

        chartList.add(BarEntry(62.5f, 1f))
        val barDataSet = BarDataSet(chartList, null)
        barDataSet.setColors(intArrayOf(Color.rgb(37, 179, 54)), 255)

        val legend : Legend? = chart?.legend
        legend?.isEnabled = false

        barDataSet.valueTextSize = 15f
        barDataSet.valueTextColor = Color.BLACK

        chart?.data = BarData(barDataSet)
        chart?.description?.isEnabled = false;
        chart?.xAxis?.isEnabled = false
        chart?.axisLeft?.isEnabled = false
        chart?.axisRight?.isEnabled = false
        chart?.setTouchEnabled(false)
        chart?.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
        chart?.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(233, 233, 233))
        chart?.setPadding(0,0,0,0)

        chart?.animateY(2000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Github issue [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1190) and the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563051/mpandroidchart-setting-chart-padding-offset) (whose solutions no longer work) the solution here is to:

1. Set the bar width to something on the `BarData` object (width is in chart units)
2. Set the horizontal axis limits to what you want so it doesn't add left/right margin (keep in mind that the HorizontalBarChart is just a rotated BarChart, so the bar length is still the y parameter, 1.0 in your example)
3. Set the min offset parameter on the chart to 0 (removes the padding)

Here is an example based on your code:

```kotlin
val chartList = listOf(
    BarEntry(62.5f, 1.0f)
)
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(chartList, null)
barDataSet.setColors(
    intArrayOf(Color.rgb(37, 179, 54)),
    255)

chart.legend.isEnabled = false

barDataSet.valueTextSize = 15f
barDataSet.valueTextColor = Color.BLACK
val d = BarData(barDataSet)

// Step 1 - Set the bar width to something so it fills the chart
d.barWidth = 1f

chart.data = d
chart.description.isEnabled = false
chart.xAxis.isEnabled = false

// Step 2 - set the horizontal axis limits
//  (removes extra horizontal space from the default limits)
chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
chart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 2f
chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
chart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
chart.setTouchEnabled(false)

// Step 3 - Set the "Min Offset" to 0 on the chart and remove the 
//  manually specified viewPortOffsets
chart.minOffset = 0f
chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(233, 233, 233))
```

And the result [image: bar demo]